# How can make my Window size be big as Screen of mac?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am using this code for help Xcode to build my Window Size as big as the screen of mac, but it does not get maxed! How we can read the size of screen and set it for view size for taking all available space on screen? It would be great getting a SwiftUI approach for the issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        Color.purple
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

    }
    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857782/define-macos-window-size-using-swiftui

Comment: @ChrisR: Thanks, but I am looking for SwiftUI way.

Comment: I rarely ever use a mac app in full screen mode. Shouldn't that preference be left to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let screenSize = NSScreen.main?.frame.size ?? CGSize(width: 800, height: 600)
    
    Color.purple
        .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
```

Comment: It is not 100% SwiftUI, but it is better than nothing. thanks

Comment: yeah, I don't know of a pure SwiftUI solution yet.e.g. would be nice to maximize a window to full screen programmatically ...

Comment: Yes, that would be nice some view that can full all available space of screen like iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cross-platform version I've created, please let me know if you spot anything amiss.

It's not yet tested on MacOS or WatchOS but compiles fine.

```
import Foundation

#if os(macOS)
import AppKit
#elseif os(iOS)
import UIKit
#elseif os(watchOS)
import WatchKit
#endif

struct Screen {
#if os(macOS)
    static var size: CGSize = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.size ?? NSScreen.main?.frame.size ?? CGSizeMake(0, 0)
#elseif os(iOS)
    static var size: CGSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
#elseif os(watchOS)
    static var size: CGSize = WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.size
#endif
    static var minX: CGFloat { 0 }
    static var minY: CGFloat { 0 }
    static var maxX: CGFloat { size.width }
    static var maxY: CGFloat { size.height }
    static var midX: CGFloat { (maxX - minX) / 2 }
    static var midY: CGFloat { (maxY - minY) / 2 }
}
```